# AssertionError after trying to convert .sbml file to ode using sbmltoodepy

Tags: python

I am trying to run a simple example using sbmltoodepy and I am receiving the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2021.2\scratches\scratch_79.py", line 8, in
ParseAndCreateModel(inputFilePath)#, jsonFilePath=None, outputFilePath=None)#, className="SBMLmodel")
File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sbmltoodepy\utilities.py", line 66, in ParseAndCreateModel
modelData = ParseSBMLFile(inputFilePath)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sbmltoodepy\parse.py", line 284, in ParseSBMLFile
assert(doc.getNumErrors() == 0)
AssertionError
```

Here is the code that I used.

```py
import sbmltoodepy
from sbmltoodepy import ParseAndCreateModel

inputFilePath = "E:/Borisov2009_insulin_EGF.xml"

ParseAndCreateModel(inputFilePath, jsonFilePath=None, outputFilePath=None, className="SBMLmodel")

model = sbmltoodepy.SBMLmodel()
model.RunSimulation(1, absoluteTolerance = 1e-12, relativeTolerance = 1e-6)
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: The path `E:/Borisov2009_insulin_EGF.xml` is controversial. Shouldn't it be like this `r"E:\Borisov2009_insulin_EGF.xml"`? Notice a backslash `\\`

Comment: I tried it, but I received the same error.